# C++ on netbeans 0xc00007b

Tags: c++, dll, netbeans, portability, execute

I tried to start an app created by me in c ++ with netbeans directly from the executable file but I get the following message...
"impossible to launch app correctly 0xc00007b"
Because according to you? I searched to the internet and have done everything everyone said on the net (install updates, directx, run as administrator, etc ...)
Please I ask you for help

Comment: just a guess, but this could be due to inconsistent 32-bit / 64-bit build / OS.

Comment: this is usually due to a missing dll dependency, difficult to tell which one without a [mre]

Comment: Looking up [C000007B](https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=c000007b) may give some insight.

Comment: Just a suggestion without a guarantee – uninstall the NetBeans, delete its configuration files from `%appdata%`, `C:\Program Files`, etc. locations. Run the `chkdsk` utility, `sfc /scannow`, use `cleanmgr.exe` (from Run) then try reinstalling the IDE with proper fresh config.

Comment: 0xc00007b can happen if there's a missing DLL dependency, a mis-match between 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs, or other architecture config issue.